# Profile C Execution

Tags: c, profiler, clock, execution-time

I wanted to see what executes faster when doing an even-odd check, modulus or bitwise comparisons. However, I'm not sure that the following is behaving correctly, as the difference is so small. I read somewhere online that bitwise should be an order of magnitude faster than modulus checking.

Is it possible that it's getting optimized away? I've just started tinkering with assembly, otherwise I'd attempt to dissect the executable a bit.

Here is a working test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// to reset the global
static const int SEED = 0x2A;

// 5B iterations, each
static const int64_t LOOPS = 5000000000;

int64_t globalVar;

// gotta call something
int64_t doSomething( int64_t input )
{
  return 1 + input;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  globalVar = SEED;
  
  // mod  
  clock_t startMod = clock();
  
  for( int64_t i=0; i<LOOPS; ++i )
  {    
    if( ( i % globalVar ) == 0 )
    {
      globalVar = doSomething(globalVar);      
    }    
  }
  
  clock_t endMod = clock();
  
  double modTime = (double)(endMod - startMod) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    
  globalVar = SEED;
  
  // bit
  clock_t startBit = clock();
  
  for( int64_t j=0; j<LOOPS; ++j )
  {
    if( ( j & globalVar ) == 0 )
    {
      globalVar = doSomething(globalVar);
    }       
  }
  
  clock_t endBit = clock();
  
  double bitTime = (double)(endBit - startBit) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  
  printf("Mod: %lf\n", modTime);
  printf("Bit: %lf\n", bitTime);  
  printf("Dif: %lf\n", ( modTime > bitTime ? modTime-bitTime : bitTime-modTime ));
}
```

5 billion iterations of each loop, with a global removing compiler optimization yields the following:

```
Mod: 93.099101
Bit: 16.701401
Dif: 76.397700
```

Comment: it could be that your doNothing is causing the entire loop check to just be optimized out as it literally does nothing. Perhaps add in a random addition operation.

Comment: @ardentsonata: I've edited my post, it didn't seem to change too much.

Comment: I wonder why you get positive values for modTime and bitTime, because `start <= end`, so `start - end <= 0`. Maybe you get an integer overflow (because of unsigneds). This would account for the big numbers you are having there. I get Mod: -2.5, Bit: -2.7, Dif: 0.2, when I run your code. Try to swap `startBit - endBit` to `endBit - startBit` and the like for `startMod - endMod`.

Comment: Also, none of this is important unless you compile with optimization.  Measuring "faster" with no optimization is kind of silly.  And, when you enable optimization, the compiler will emit vastly different code, and it will almost certainly optimize your entire loop away (because it can tell that the loop does nothing).  You need to make sure the loop has a side effect.  For example: increment a volatile variable inside.

Comment: @Nobody, that did it! So sorry. New values: Mod: 9.852450
Bit: 6.406744
Dif: 3.445706

Comment: @ArjunShankar: Done, good call.

Comment: *I've just started tinkering with assembly, otherwise I'd attempt to dissect the executable a bit.* That means that now is the perfect time to attempt to dissect the assembly!  You'll never learn if you don't try.

Comment: @Josh - If you really want to see a difference, change your % and & operators' right-hand-side expressions to be variable instead of constant.  But also see my answer below for more suggestions to avoid a clever compiler from optimizing away its variableness.

Comment: `x % y` and `x & y` are two **VERY** different operations. You will have a vastly different number of calls to `doSomething`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most compilers will compile both of the following to EXACTLY the same machine instruction(s):

```
if( ( i % 2 ) == 0 )

if( ( i & 1 ) == 0 )
```

...even without ANY "optimization" turned on.  The reason is that you are MOD-ing and AND-ing with constant values, and a %2 operation is, as any compiler writer should know, functionally equivalent to an &1 operation.  In fact, MOD by any power-of-2 has an equivalent AND operation.  If you really want to test the difference, you'll need to make the right-hand-side of both operations be variable, and to be absolutely sure the compiler's cleverness isn't thwarting your efforts, you'll need to bury the variables' initializations somewhere that the compiler can't tell at that point what its runtime value will be; i.e. you'll need to pass the values into a GLOBALLY-DECLARED (i.e. not 'static') test function as parameters, in which case the compiler can't trace back to their definition & substitute the variables with constants, because theoretically any external caller could pass any values in for those parameters.  Alternatively, you could leave the code in main() and define the variables globally, in which case the compiler can't substitute them with constants because it can't know for sure that another function may have altered the value of the global variables.

Incidentally, this same issue exists for divide operations....  Divisions by constant powers-of-two can be substituted  with an equivalent right-shift (>>) operation.  The same trick works for multiplication (<<), but the benefits are less (or nonexistant) for multiplications.  True division operations just take a long time in hardware, though significant improvements have been made in most modern processors vs. even 15 years ago, division operations still take maybe 80 clock cycles, while a >> operation takes only a single cycle.  You're not going to see an "order of magnitude" improvement using bitwise tricks on modern processors, but most compilers will still use those tricks because there is still some noticeable improvement.

EDIT: On some embedded processors (and, unbelievable though it was, the original Sparc desktop/workstation processor versions before v8), there isn't even a divide instruction at all.  All true divide & mod operations on such processors must be performed entirely in software, which can be a monstrously expensive operation.  In that sort of environment, you surely would see an order of magnitude difference.

Answer (score 3):

`gcc foo.c -std=c99 -S -O0` **(note, I specifically did `-O0`)** for x86 gave me the *same* assembly for both loops. Operator [strength reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strength_reduction) meant that both `if`s used an `andl` to get the job done (which is faster than a modulo on Intel machines):

First Loop:

```
.L6:
        movl    72(%esp), %eax
        andl    $1, %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     .L5
        call    doNothing
.L5:
        addl    $1, 72(%esp)
.L4:
        movl    LOOPS, %eax
        cmpl    %eax, 72(%esp)
        jl      .L6
```

Second Loop:

```
.L9:
        movl    76(%esp), %eax
        andl    $1, %eax
        testl   %eax, %eax
        jne     .L8
        call    doNothing
.L8:
        addl    $1, 76(%esp)
.L7:
        movl    LOOPS, %eax
        cmpl    %eax, 76(%esp)
        jl      .L9
```

The miniscule difference you see is probably because of the resolution/inaccuracy of `clock`.

Answer (score 2):

Bitwise checking takes only a single machine instruction ("and ...,0x01"); that's pretty hard to beat.

Modulo check will absolutely be slower if you have a dumb compiler that actually computes modulo by taking remainders (sometimes including a subroutine call to modulo routine!).   Smart compilers know about the modulo function and generate code for it directly; if they have any decent optimization they know that "modulo(x,2)" can be implemented with the same AND trick above.

Our [PARLANSE](http://www.semdesigns.com/products/parlanse/index.html) compiler does this as a matter of course.  I'd be surprised if widely available C and C++ compilers don't do this too.

With such "good" compilers, it won't matter which way you write odd/even (or even "is power of two") checks; it will be pretty damn fast.

Comment: Actually DIVIDE and AND instructions both normally take only a single machine instruction.  But instructions do not always take the same amount of time to execute; a divide instruction is typically among the longest-to-execute instructions available on a processor, which is why compilers will automatically convert them to bit-shifts (or MOD operations to AND operations) whenever possible.

Comment: Divide and And both take 1 machine *instruction* but we're talking about execution time.   And your point about compilers is the point I made.